# Is it ok to not call Socket.close()

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I am setting a server using c#, it has an infinite loop contains the Socket.ReceiveFrom, so the application will always be idle until a message is received, the problem is I read in a website: "When an application has completed communications on a socket, it needs to close the connection to free the resource", so does that mean in each time I receive a message I have to close the socket?

doing that means I have to reinitialize the constructor of the socket on each time the loop is repeating it self, so I searched about: "does sockets close automatically when an application is terminated", but didn't find any answer for this.

the following two codes will make it more clear:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // With out closing
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8888);

    Socket sckt = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    sckt.Bind(endpoint);

    IPEndPoint senderEndPoint = new IPEndPoint((long)IPAddress.Any.AddressFamily, 0);

    EndPoint remote = (EndPoint)endpoint;
    Console.WriteLine("Listening");

    while (true)
    {
        // receive data from sender
        int recv = sckt.ReceiveFrom(data, ref remote);

        // Get sender ip address
        senderEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)remote;
        Console.WriteLine(senderEndPoint.Address.ToString());

        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
        // Console.WriteLine(message);
        if (message.Equals("test"))
            //do something
    }
}
```

With closing:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Listening");
               while (true)
                 {
                 byte[] data = new byte[1024];

                IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8888);

                Socket sckt = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                sckt.Bind(endpoint);

                IPEndPoint senderEndPoint = new IPEndPoint((long)IPAddress.Any.AddressFamily, 0);

                EndPoint remote = (EndPoint)endpoint;



                    //receive data from sender
                    int recv = sckt.ReceiveFrom(data, ref remote);

                    //Get sender ip address
                    senderEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)remote;
                    Console.WriteLine(senderEndPoint.Address.ToString());


                    string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                    //Console.WriteLine(message);
                    if (message.Equals("lol"))
                        //do something

                    sckt.Close();


                }
}
```

Comment: How about writing your question with full stops and paragraphs? Would enable/improve reabability.

Comment: I suggest using *standard* `using` pattern for `IDisposable`: `using(Socket sckt = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp) {...};
                `

Comment: @UweKeim thanks for the suggestion, it has to be better now ;)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks for commenting, so If I used using(Socket sckt = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp), I don't need to worry about closing the socket in my code?

Comment: @Hussein AlHroub: exactly, that's the very purpose of `using` pattern

Comment: " so does that mean in each time I receive a message I have to close the socket?" - that depends : are you done with the *socket*? some APIs are single-message-per-socket, and some APIs are multiple messages on the same socket. If the latter, then no: don't close. If the former, then yes: do

Comment: No you do not need to open and close socket for receiving each datagram, but you need to know when to stop reading to get a meaningful information, also once your application is closed the socket will destroyed automatically, but it is a good practice to close it manually when it is not needed.

Comment: @muaz "also once your application is closed the socket will destroyed automatically" thanks, that's what I was searching for, just to clarify, this is a console application with an infinity loop, the application keep on reading any message it receives to do some instructions, so the only way "currently" to exist the application is by clicking the 'X' button from the window, so I always need the application to be ready to listen for any incoming messages, now to close the socket I added ConsoleCtrlHandlerDelegate, which will be invoked once I exit the application, and there I close the socket.